# create dynamic button inside dialogbox in android

Tags: android, button, dynamic, nullpointerexception, dialog

I'm trying to create Dynamic buttons inside a Dialogbox , I'm able to create it outside dialog box , but not able to create inside dialogbox .

```
cust.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        custom = new Dialog(MyActivity.this);
        custom.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        custom.setContentView(R.layout.hor);
        custom.show();

        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.content1);
        Button btn[] = new Button[20];
        for( int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            btn[i] = new Button(MyActivity.this);
            btn[i].setText("Button " + i);
            linearLayout.addView(btn[i]);
        }
    }
});`
```

getting Error on : linearLayout.addView(btn[i]);

```
02-22 00:51:17.919    5437-5437/com.example.DialogTry E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.DialogTry.MyActivity$1.onClick(MyActivity.java:135)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17446)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
        at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:126)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line-

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.content1);
```

to this-

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) custom.findViewById(R.id.content1);
```